# Datagrid ComboBox Binding

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a table in my database that represents a list of areas. I would like to get all of these items in this list and bind them to a combobox dropdown in my datagrid. This currently works, and my grid column displays this dropdown. However, when I select an item in the cell and move to the next row, the cell becomes blank.  Also, if the entry in the database has a saved value of "area1", and my dropdown list has "area1,area2,area3,etc", when the grid loads, it doesn't autoselect area1, the cell is simply blank.

In my model:

```
comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = ctx.AREAS;//db context loading all areas into combobox
```

In my xaml:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="some header" x:Name="comboboxColumn1" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Name}" />
....
```

How would I go about setting this selected value so that it is equal to whatever entry is in the db?

Comment: I've had terrible luck with the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, and much better luck by using a custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` that just has a combo box in it, or better yet just use a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.selectedvaluepath.aspx) value to your variable property. The `DisplayMemberPath` is for what is shown, and `SelectedValuePath` is what is selected. `SelectedItem` is the actual item that is selected.

Comment: Here is what worked:          <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="Department Id" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Name}" x:Name="comboboxColumn1" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ZONE.GACC}" /> Where GACC is the entity, and Name is a property in GACC.